# Is Fault Tolerant Heap bad in developing Qt C++ app?

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory, fault-tolerant-heap

I am coding Qt C++ app and suddenly Fault Tolerant Heap appears. Everything works fine but after run of app its writes to console:

FTH: (some_number): *** Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes. ***

I read little bit about it and it looks like its helping to avoid crashes. But my application will not be use only on my computer. I need to use it on more computers. Will this Fault Tolerant Heap be applied on app on any computer ? Is there any disadvantage to keep it enable during coding ? Should I disable it ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I would disable it, it's generally good to know as soon as possible about bugs in your code.

Comment: There is a the story of MS developing a fault tolerant heap for an early version of Windows (version 2 IIRC) because one particular company (Adobe) couldn't write correct code. MS were rightly worried that when Photoshop started crashing on the new Windows version they would get blamed not Adobe.

Comment: Set this registry value to 0: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\FTH\Enabled

Comment: Trying to make memory-management problems as non-obvious as possible, rather than as obvious as possible, seems like a bad idea to me.  I feel like Microsoft is headed in the wrong direction here :)